# How to run a .class file that is in another directory

Tags: java, exec

My question is that how to run a .class java file in a directory using exec() or ProcessBuilder class. This only works if the .class file is in the same directory (as the java program).

Comment: Have you considered more simple alternatives than using exec()? E.g. adding the class to the classpath and just importing/calling it the usual Java way?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to spawn an entirely new process? Then you should use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"java","-cp","/path/to/classes/dir/","com.foo.MyClass"});
```

If you want something in the same process, you can create a new ClassLoader which knows how to load your .class file.  You can then use reflection to get the class object from the classloader, and call its "main" method or something like that.  You'll need to use reflection because the class will not be available in the default class loader.

Comment: I left out some args to the exec, namely the -cp for setting the classpath (if you need anything besides the single class file)

Comment: Java isn't launched that way.  You need to give an absolute path to the classpath, and then give the fully-qualified class name.  Java doesn't work by supplying the class file.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved Guys thanks for your replies... :)

Solution I've used

String path = "D:\work"; //Path for my program to execute

String program = "Test";  //My Program name

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java","-classpath",path, program);

Comment: If you ever come back to the site, you should accept your own answer.